# automorphisms of local rings vs local change of coordinates

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, automorphism-groups, local-rings

Let $R$ be a local (commutative, associative) ring over a field of zero characteristic.  (My typical examples are $k[[x_1,..,x_p]]/I$, $k\{x_1,.,x_p\}/I$, $C^\infty(\Bbb{R}^p,0)$.  If it helps one can assume $R$ to be Henselian.)

I'd like to think of the ring automorphisms, $Aut(R)$, (those that act on the field as identity) as the local changes of coordinates, "$Aut(Spec(R))$". The two objects certainly coincide  if $R$ is the localization of an affine ring.
 
More generally, let $S=k[x_1,..,x_p]/I$, let $S\subseteq R\subseteq \hat{S}$, the completion with respect to $(x_1,..,x_p)$. Then the two objects coincide for $R$.

But for $R=C^\infty(\Bbb{R}^p,0)$ there are endomorphisms which do not come from the local maps of coordinates. See [Page 5](https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=0034-5318&vol=12&iss=1&rank=3). (In this particular example one has an endomorphism, not an automorphism. Still, it is not clear that here $Aut(R)=``Aut(Spec(R))"=Aut(\Bbb{R}^p,0)$, the later is the group of germs of local diffeomorphisms).

1. Suppose $R$ is "geometric enough", so that one can speak of $Spec(R)$, its local coordinates, a local change of them. Does every local change of coordinates (that preserves the origin) extend to an automorphism of $R$?
2. For which "geometric" rings rings $Aut(R)=``Aut(Spec(R))"$? (i.e. the group of all the automorphisms of $R$ vs the group of the local coordinate changes in $Spec(R)$.) what is the official notation for the "geometric" subgroup $``Aut(Spec(R))"$ of $Aut(R)$?  (The notation $Aut(Spec(R))$ is somewhat heavy/lengthy.)

Any paper/review on the state of the art in this direction?

Comment: I think you haven't actually stated which two objects you want to coincide.

Comment: What does $IC^{\infty}(...)$ stand for?

Comment: $I$ is separated by comma from the ring of germs of infinitely differentiable functions

Comment: Oh, when I first read it my tablet was displaying it the wrong way. I can now see the comma, sorry :)

Comment: I still don't understand the question. Isn't Aut(R) = Aut(Spec R) an immediate consequence of what scheme theory is for? And again, "Spec R" makes sense for any commutative ring. Now that I've reread it for the fourth time it starts making sense, but I humbly think it could be written more clearly.

Comment: @bananastack  If the ring is Noetherian then we have the standard dictionary to the scheme theory. I'm not sure about the non-Noetherian case. In particular there are many cases when Aut(R) is bigger than  Aut(Spec R).

Comment: @DmitryKerner: fix a base ring A (eg A = Z, R, C...). The category of A-algebras is equivalent to the category of affine schemes over Spec A. Hence, Aut(R) is the same as Aut(Spec R). Noetherian has nothing to do with it, I'm still somewhat confused by your question.

Comment: @bananastack: Probably the confusion occurs due to my ignorance, I'm speaking in classical terms. Here is a simple example. Fix two flat functions $\tau_1,\tau_2\in C^{\infty}(\Bbb{R},0)$, which are algebraically independent. Let $R=\Bbb{R}\{x\}[\{x^{-j}\tau_1\}_{j\in\Bbb{N}},\{x^{-j}\tau_2\}_{j\in\Bbb{N}}]$. Define $\phi$ as identity on any converging power series and $\phi(\tau_1)=\tau_2$, $\phi(\tau_2)=\tau_1$. Extend this to $\phi\in Aut(R)$. We get an automorphism which does not come from the local change of coordinates.

Comment: I guess one can construct a lot of "non-geometric" automorphisms of $C^{\infty}(\Bbb{R},0)$ in this way, using the axiom of choice.

Comment: @DmitryKerner: what is a local change of coordinates?

Comment: @bananastack: again, speaking in the classical terms, in the $C^\infty(\Bbb{R}^p,0)$ case we have the classical $x\to \phi(x)$, it creates the ring automorphism $f(x)\to f(\phi^{-1}(x))$. I'm not sure the notation $Aut(Spec(R))$ is appropriate here. (Some other notation?) Such a thing cannot be done in an arbitrary ring, only when every element of the ring "can be written as some explicit expression of the generators". as in $C^\infty$ case. I'm not sure how to formalize this.

Answer (score 2):

About $C^\infty(\mathbb R^p,0)$, the ring of germs of smooth functions, I have the following remarks:

It's ideal of flat functions is notoriously ill behaved. In the final topology on this ring for the mapping
$C^\infty(\mathbb R^p)\to C^\infty(\mathbb R^p,0)$ it is in the closure of zero. There are results available classifying closed ideals, see the book [Tougeron: Ideaux des functions differentiable, Springer 1972].

The exotic automorphism that you describe involves a non-continuous part. The Whitney extension theorem gives an extension operator from Whitney jets to functions, and describes when this extension operator can be chosen continuous. If I remember correctly, this is the case for closed sets which are the closures of their open interiors. A point is not of this class. This is an indication that the exotic automorphisms all come from discontinuous constructions.

If you do not insist on rings of germs but on the full rings $C^\infty(M)$ for smooth manifolds $M$, you have perfect duality between the category of manifolds and the these rings. See chapter 8 of [this book](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf). As spectrum you have to take the ideals of codimension 1. Ideals of finite codimension have interesting interpretations in terms of differential geometric constructions. See also the thorough treatment of $C^\infty$-rings in the first chapter of the book

- Moerdijk, Ieke; Reyes, Gonzalo E.:
  Models for smooth infinitesimal analysis. Springer-Verlag, New York, 1991. x+399 pp.

and the characterization of rings of smooth functions of manifolds in [this paper](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/ci-alg.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! Still, I do not know any place where a "non-geometric" automorphism of $C^\infty$ is constructed. (i.e. an automorphism which is identity on all the polynomials but not identity on the flat functions). Could you suggest smth?